# Deploy Python code on Apache HTTPD using Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I need some guidance to deploy Python code using Jenkins.

I have a Python code on my git repository and I need to package the code in the form of WAR or any other executable and Deploy the code on Apache httpd server installed on Linux machine.

However, In my Previous scenario I was able to successfully packaged my java code in WAR and deployed successfully in the tomcat server.

Hence I need to understand regarding the Python code whether it would be packaged in the same way as Java code or any other mechanism needs to be followed.

Please guide me.